# The Spotify Play Button doesn't refresh all the songs

Tags: button, spotify, playback

I'm using the Spotify Play Button as a promotion tool for a festival.
I started last year and would like to refresh the whole list with new artists so all the subscribers remain. So basically I deleted all the artists from last year and added the new artists for the current edition. However, for some reason, some of the artists are still in the Spotify Play button visisble while in the application itself only the new artists are visisble.

Does anyone knows how to deal with this problem?
I would be very pleased if I can use the same list, as all the subscribers remain.

Thanks in advance.
E.g. spotify:user:1117955849:playlist:1BUQAapmht5TvnyjzfQvYt

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not seeing the correct songs is because of a bug in the Spotify backend system. There is a playlist cache that doesn't correctly mark lists as dirty after edits in some situations and still returns the old data. There is unfortunately currently no way to deal with this for you except for waiting if you want to use the same playlist. Usually a day, sometimes two.

Two workarounds exist to get a widget with the correct tracks immediately.

1. Create a new playlist
2. Use trackset, described here: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/documentation/

My hope is that we can fix it so you never see this problem to begin with.

I work at Spotify and I am ashamed we haven't fixed this one yet